# angular.js:14700 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="bottom-right bottom-timer time botton10">
  <div class="work-clock" ng-bind="workCntrl.getClockString(work)">
  </div>
</div>
```

`getClockString(work)` gives error :

> [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"workCntrl.getClockString(work)","newVal":"132:0:15:6","oldVal":"132:0:15:5"},

Comment: can you show what your `getClockString` function is doing?

Comment: can you pls add more code? or create a plnkr?

Comment: yeah it returns a string value "132:0:15:6"

Comment: basically, you shouldn't change the models during rendering. Try using: `ng-init="clockString=workCntrl.getClockString(work)"` and then use `ng-bind="clockString"`

Comment: I need to update the clock string values per second but here after initialising , it gives me a fixed constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `getClockString` method returns one string value then call it inside angular's `$interval` service. Update your template code to:

```
<div class="bottom-right bottom-timer time botton10">
  <div class="work-clock" ng-init="workCntrl.getClockStringEverySecond(work)" 
     ng-bind="workCntrl.clockString">
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller update your code to:

```
workCntrl.getClockStringEverySecond = function(work) {
    $interval(function () {
        workCntrl.clockString= workCntrl.getClockString(work);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Here, `clockString` is a scope variable which will be updated every second by getting value from getClockString method. This way you'll not get above issue.

**[Generic Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/G47GErarP7lPs2z7VQTi?p=preview)**